# How to use Canvas.clipRects to highlight face rects?

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, android-image, android-bitmap

I have a Bitmap with multiple faces. I want to highlight each face such that, face rects have the original color and the rest of the area is blacked out.

I did something like,

```
                   for(int i=0; i<getNumFaces(); i++)
                    {   

                    Rect rect = getRect();                                  
                    canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
                    canvas.clipRect(rect, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK, Mode.SRC_ATOP);


                    }                       

                  confirmationView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
```

But this makes my entire image black. I kinda know the reason but not able to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but try this:

```
               canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
               for(int i=0; i<getNumFaces(); i++)
                {   

                Rect rect = getRect();                                  
                canvas.clipRect(rect, Region.Op.UNION);


                }                       
                Rect all = new Rect(0,0,mutableBitmap.getWidth(), mutableBitmap.getHeight());
                canvas.clipRect(all , Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

              confirmationView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
```

Note:  I haven't actually run this.  But its building one big clipping region consisting of all the rects you want to keep.  Then its creating a clip consisting of all the bitmap except the areas you want to keep.  Then its coloring the part you don't want to keep in.